# What happens when the attenuation between radios in an RF test bed becomes higher than the RF leakage attenuation of the coax cables?

Tags: rf, cables, interference, shielding, attenuation

If I have an RF testbed with radios connected to each other via an attenuation matrix, what happens when that attenuation between radios exceeds the rated attenuation of the braided shield coax cable (110-120 dB) for RF leakage? Should I expect interference and cross-talk to increase severely?

Comment: Show a diagram to avoid ambiguity

Comment: Your question suggests that one radio is used as a signal source to test the other radio. Clean single-signal generators are expensive with extensive internal shielding, unlike a radio.

Comment: @glen_geek One radio sends a signal and that signal gets repeated in-series to the next radio until the end of the chain. If we assume the radio cases do not have significant/problematic RF leakage, I'm wondering if the total fixed attenuation between radios being larger than the cable's rated shielding attenuation has any meaning.